# Подравить if else

Tags: javascript

Из функций arm, color передаю переменную arm, color у функцию check для проверки, а проверка не происходит :( 
В чём подвох?

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--
function check(temp){
if (arm == "none" &&  color == "black"){
alert('Работает');
}
else
{
alert('Не работает');
}
}

function color(param){
var color;
color=param;
check(color);
}

function arm(param){
var arm;
arm=param;
check(arm);
}
//-->
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: 1) я не вижу инициализации color  
2) функция check не увидит переменную arm внутри функции arm. Для check arm - это функция в области видимости уровнем выше.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну как то так наверно, и почитайте про область видимости переменных в Js.

```
function check(arm, color){
    if ((arm == 'none') && (color == 'black')) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

var result = check('none', 'black');
alert(result);
```